# Simple todo list VanillaJS - repository pattern

Tags: javascript, beginner, repository

I'm new in JavaScript, so I was looking for some reviews and advice for better code quality.

```
import Todo from './Todo.js';

export default class Repository {
  constructor(todos = []) {
    this.todos = todos;
    this.storage = localStorage;
  }

  addTodo(todo, save=true) {
    this.todos = [...this.todos.filter(item => item.uuid !== todo.uuid), todo];
    if (save) {
      this.saveTodos();
    }
  }

  removeTodo(todo) {
    this.todos = [...this.todos.filter(item => item.uuid !== todo.uuid)];
    this.saveTodos();
  }

  saveTodos() {
    this.storage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(this.todos));
  }

  loadTodos() {
    const storageTodos = JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem('todos'));
    if (storageTodos !== null) {
      storageTodos.map(todo => this.addTodo(Object.assign(new Todo(), todo)), false);
    }

    return this.todos;
  }
}
```

https://github.com/adbo/todo_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### General points

- There is no need to add `localStorage` to the `Repository` object as it is part of the global this.
- You can access localStorage values directly by the key name <sup>**[.1]**</sup>.  Eg setting `localStorage.myData = "Hi World"`, getting `const message = localStorage.myData`, to check if it exists `localStorage.myData !== undefined`, to empty a value `localStorage.myData = undefined`, and to delete `delete localStorage.myData`
- LocalStorage should not be trusted. Calling `JSON.parse` on data from local storage should always be wrapped in a try catch in case the data has been modified by a 3rd party.
- Using `filter` to remove items from an array is not as efficient as locating the item's index and splicing it. Even better would be to store the todo array as a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) indexed by `uuid` see second example.
- You have some poor naming due to the repeated prefixing of todo to all the functions. I can imagine that the Repository is called `todoList` and thus is would be `todoList.addTodo`  `todoList.removeTodo` and so on.  Would be far more readable if you drop the todo . Eg `todoList.add`,  `todoList.remove`, ...
- You are repeating code. Both `add` and `remove` functions filter (remove) a todo. I would be better for `add` to call `remove`

### Good OO design

Javascripts class syntax is something you should avoid as it forces you to create objects with poor encapsulation (if you don't use the "abomination" that is `#` private  prefix) Javascript has several very robust object patterns that provide air tight encapsulation and should be used if you wish to follow good OO design.

The examples shows and immediately invoked function (IIF) pattern that defines the Object `Repository` as a function returning an ad hock `Object` that encapsulates via closure.

The `todos` array (or map) is isolated and not directly accessible. It uses a getter to return the array of todos as a shallow copy

### Examples

Both examples use IIF pattern to encapsulate the object created from the named `Repository`

Note that it has slightly different behavior than your object.

You can instantiate the object with or without the `new` token. Eg `todos = Repository()` or `todos = new Repository()`

The first example store data in an array that it keeps private, copied on creation and copied when accessed via the getter `todos`.

#### IFF ad hock

```
export default Repository = (() => {
    const save = (todos) => localStorage.todos = JSON.stringify(todos);
    const load = () => {
        try { return localStorage.todos ? JSON.parse(localStorage.todos) : [] }
        catch(e) { return [] }
    }
    return function(todos = []) {
        todos = [...todos]; 
        return Object.freeze({
            get todos() { return [...todos] },
            remove(todo, saveChanges = true) {
                const idx = todos.findIndex(item => item.uuid !== todo.uuid);                
                idx > -1 && todos.splice(idx, 1);  
                saveChanges && save(todos);                
            },                
            add(todo, saveChanges = true) {
                this.remove(todo, false);
                todos.push(toDo);
                saveChanges && save(todos);
            },
            save() { save(todos) },
            load() {
                load().forEach(todo => this.add(Object.assign(new Todo(), todo), false));
                return this.todos;
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

#### IFF with Map

This example uses a map to improve the efficiency of removing items and reduces the source size. It behaves identically to the first example.

Also as using `this` does present a security concern (even in modules) thus example references self via the named constant `API`

```
export default Repository = (() => {
    const save = (todos) => localStorage.todos = JSON.stringify(todos);
    const load = () => {
        try { return localStorage.todos ? JSON.parse(localStorage.todos) : [] }
        catch(e) { return [] }
    }
    return function(todosInit = []) {
        const API = Object.freeze({
            get todos() { return [...todos.values()] },
            remove(todo, saveChanges = true) {
                todos.delete(todo.uuid);
                saveChanges && API.save();                
            },                
            add(todo, saveChanges = true) {
                API.remove(todo, false);
                todos.set(todo.uuid, todo);
                saveChanges && API.save();
            },
            save() { save(API.todos) },
            load() {
                load().forEach(todo => API.add(Object.assign(new Todo(), todo), false));
                return API.todos;
            }
        });
        return API;
    }
})();
```

### Notes

<sup>**[.1]** Note that [MDN localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Basic_concepts) page cites ["The pitfalls of using objects as maps"](https://2ality.com/2012/01/objects-as-maps.html) as reason not to use direct key access. Why only warn on localStorage why not have the same warning on every Object? Get with it MDN!!</sup>